# Why couldn't I call eval() in this way?

Tags: php

Why is the following code fails to compile:

```
<?php
  $str = "echo \"ok\"";
  $func = "eval";
  $func ($str);
?>
```

And php tells me eval was undefined.

Comment: Because `eval` is not really a function, it's a language construct: *"Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions."* http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php `<-` (it's written in the docs).

Comment: @Asad thanks to starx's answer, I finally know what "evaling eval" means in your comment ;-P right, that's what I'm doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, `eval` is a "language construct", not a function. (Notice It turns keyword-color in syntax highlighting editors.) Language constructs cannot be called using the variable function syntax `$func()` or used with other function-specific things like `is_callable()`.

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php:

> Variable functions won't work with language constructs such as echo, print, unset(), isset(), empty(), include, require and the like. Utilize wrapper functions to make use of any of these constructs as variable functions.

Answer (score 1):

[`eval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#refsect1-function.eval-notes) is not a function its a language construct and variable functions won't work with language constructs.

Answer (score 1):

[`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) cannot be called using a variable function. If you don't understand what a [variable function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) is? look at the following part of your code

```
  $func = "eval";
  $func ($str); //Here $func becomes eval upon execution making it a variable function
```

If you look at the manual reference, its clearly [noted](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#refsect1-function.eval-notes)

> Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions.

Answer (score -1):

You got Wrong..the code, maybe like example..

```
<?php
    $eval_code =    '$my_name = "Swashata";' .
                    '$your_name = "John";' .
                    'return $your_name;' .
                    'echo $my_name;';
    $the_name = eval( $eval_code );
    echo '<p>$the_name has got a value ' . $the_name . '</p>';
?>
```

Comment: So... what's the big difference in your code? What is wrong with the OP's code? Why does it fail?